BautifulSoup buscar clase exactamente python
Tengo este código html (es de transfermarkt, solo pongo una parte)
<td class="hauptlink">
    <a href="/geronimo-rulli/profil/spieler/229604">
        Gerónimo Rulli
    </a>
</td>
<td class="rechts hauptlink">
    <a href="/geronimo-rulli/marktwertverlauf/spieler/229604">
        10,00 mill. €
    </a>
</td>
<td class="hauptlink">
    <a href="/miguel-angel-moya/profil/spieler/26065">
        Miguel Ángel Moyá
    </a>
</td>

Estoy utilizando el método find_all para coger los nombres, la clase 'hauptlink' de la siguiente forma ->
Soup = soup.find_all('td', class_=('hauptlink'))

el problema es que coge la clase "rechts hauptlink" de igual manera, cuando yo solo quiero obtener la primera, he probado con expresiones regulares pero no he dado con la tecla.
Gracias por la ayuda!
Un saludo

Eso pasa porque class es una de los atributos multi-valor (una misma etiqueta puede tener más de una clase). Este es el caso de tus tds con "rechts hauptlink".
Estos atributos son almacenados como listas y al buscar con class_='hauptlink' simplemente comprueba si 'hauptlink' está en la lista (y está en todas).
Si fuerzas que todos tus atributos se almacenen como strings funcionará:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
    <td class="hauptlink">
        <a href="/geronimo-rulli/profil/spieler/229604">
            Gerónimo Rulli
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="rechts hauptlink">
        <a href="/geronimo-rulli/marktwertverlauf/spieler/229604">
            10,00 mill. €
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="hauptlink">
        <a href="/miguel-angel-moya/profil/spieler/26065">
            Miguel Ángel Moyá
        </a>
    </td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser', multi_valued_attributes=None)


tags = soup.find_all('td', class_="hauptlink")
print(*tags, sep="\n\n")


<td class="hauptlink">
<a href="/geronimo-rulli/profil/spieler/229604">
            Gerónimo Rulli
        </a>
</td>

<td class="hauptlink">
<a href="/miguel-angel-moya/profil/spieler/26065">
            Miguel Ángel Moyá
        </a>
</td>


No obstante esto puede que no te resulte conveniente, tienes otras dos alternativas:
Filtrar usando una función
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'td' and tag.get('class') == ['hauptlink'])

Observa que la comparación es con una lista (['hauptlink']) por lo comentado al inicio. En el caso de tu segundo td tag.get('class') retornará ['rechts', 'hauptlink'].
Usar un selector CSS
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.select('td[class="hauptlink"]')


Funciona perfecto !
Muchas gracias
